# In Refinery CMS, how can I write a simple functional test using Test::Unit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms

This is my functional test:

```
require 'test_helper'

class PagesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  tests Refinery::PagesController
  include Devise::TestHelpers 

  def setup
    Rails.application.load_seed 
  end

  test "about us page" do
    assert_equal "about", Refinery::Page.find_by_slug("about").slug

    get :show, { use_route: :about }
    assert_response :success
  end

end
```

This is what I get when I run it:

```
$ rake test TEST=test/functional/pages_controller_test.rb
Run options:

# Running tests:

F

Finished tests in 3.709222s, 0.2696 tests/s, 0.8088 assertions/s.

  1) Failure:
test_access_about_page(PagesControllerTest) [test/functional/pages_controller_test.rb:17]:
Expected response to be a <:success>, but was <404>

1 tests, 3 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
rake aborted!
```

How should I route the `get` request in my test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The section on functional testing](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#functional-tests) from the Rails Engines guide helped me figure this out.

This is the `get` request I needed:

```
get :show, {use_route: :refinery, path: :about}
```

The full test that now passes:

```
require 'test_helper'

class PagesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  tests Refinery::PagesController
  include Devise::TestHelpers 

  def setup
    Rails.application.load_seed 
  end

  test "about us page" do
    assert_equal "about", Refinery::Page.find_by_slug("about").slug

    get :show, {use_route: :refinery, path: :about}
    assert @response.body.include? "About Us"
    assert_response :success
  end

end
```